# How do I programatically create NSTableView in Swift for MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

With the Swift code below, I'm trying to programmatically display a list of shortcuts in a table on macOS.

However, the table appears empty on the screen.

Interestingly, there are no error messages being generated, and when I use `debugPrint` within the `tableView` function, it outputs column name, row, and correct data for each cell.

Thanks for your help.

```swift
class ShortcutsWindowController: NSWindowController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    var shortcuts: [Shortcut]
    var tableView: NSTableView!
    init(shortcuts: [Shortcut]) {
        self.shortcuts = shortcuts
        super.init(window: nil)
        for shortcut in shortcuts {
            debugPrint(shortcut.name, shortcut.key, shortcut.modifiers, shortcut.keyName)
        }
        setupWindow()
        setupTableView()
        window?.contentView?.needsDisplay = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupWindow() {
        let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300),
                              styleMask: [.titled, .closable],
                              backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        self.window = window
        self.window?.title = "Customize Shortcuts"
    }
    
    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView = NSTableView(frame: self.window!.contentView!.bounds)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        let nameColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("NameColumn"))
        nameColumn.title = "Name"
        tableView.addTableColumn(nameColumn)
        let hotkeyColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("HotkeyColumn"))
        hotkeyColumn.title = "Hotkey"
        tableView.addTableColumn(hotkeyColumn)
        self.window?.contentView?.addSubview(tableView)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return shortcuts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let shortcut = shortcuts[row]
        debugPrint(tableColumn?.title, row)
        switch tableColumn?.identifier {
        case NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("NameColumn"):
            let cellView = NSTableCellView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableColumn!.width, height: tableView.rowHeight))
            let textField = NSTextField(frame: cellView.bounds)
            textField.stringValue = shortcut.name
            textField.isEditable = false
            textField.isBezeled = false
            textField.drawsBackground = false
            textField.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height] // Resize with the cell view
            cellView.addSubview(textField)
            debugPrint("Cell Name:", shortcut.name)
            return cellView

        case NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("HotkeyColumn"):
            let cellView = NSTableCellView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableColumn!.width, height: tableView.rowHeight))
            let button = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableColumn!.width, height: tableView.rowHeight))
            button.title = shortcut.keyName
            button.tag = row
            button.target = self
            button.action = #selector(reassignShortcut(_:))
            cellView.addSubview(button)
            debugPrint("Cell Hotkey", shortcut.keyName)
            return cellView

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    @objc func reassignShortcut(_ sender: NSButton) {
        // logic
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I would expect `self.window?.contentView` to be nil here. Have you checked that it isn't? (In almost all cases of "nothing happens," the answer is "something is nil." Check for that across your program.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just checked, and contentView is not nil. ~if let view = self.window!.contentView { debugPrint("Pass") }~ works. The window also has table with squares in them, so something seems to be there.

Comment: Did you inspect the views with View UI Hierarchy? How many shortcuts? No scroll view? Is the window visible? I tried your code and I see a table, it looks weird but it's visible. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: The other version of "something is nil" is "you're not looking at what you think you're looking at." Are you certain that this NSWindow is actually on-screen, and is the window you're looking at? I would try putting something trivial in the window rather than the table view, and make sure you're doing what you think you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The following programmatic approach to creating a tableView works on my system.  I was unable to see the tableView until I added a scrollView for it to sit in.  The source code may be run in XCode by creating a Swift project, adding a new file called 'main.swift', and copy/pasting this code into it.  Delete the pre-supplied AppDelegate to avoid duplicate symbols. I tried to use as much of your code as possible.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    var window:NSWindow!
    var shortcuts = [["name": "print", "key":"P", "modifier":"shift"],
                     ["name": "copy",  "key":"C", "modifier":"alt"],
                     ["name": "cut",   "key":"X", "modifier":"alt"],
                     ["name": "paste", "key":"V", "modifier":"alt"]]
    
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        
        return shortcuts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cellView = NSTableCellView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableColumn!.width, height: tableView.rowHeight))
        
        switch tableColumn?.identifier {
        case NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("NameColumn"):
            
            let textField = NSTextField(frame: cellView.bounds)
            textField.stringValue = shortcuts[row]["name"]!
            textField.isEditable = false
            textField.isBezeled = false
            textField.drawsBackground = false
            textField.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height] // Resize with the cell view
            cellView.addSubview(textField)
            return cellView
            
        case NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("HotkeyColumn"):
            
            let textField = NSTextField(frame: cellView.bounds)
            textField.stringValue = shortcuts[row]["key"]!
            textField.isEditable = false
            textField.isBezeled = false
            textField.drawsBackground = false
            textField.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height] // Resize with the cell view
            cellView.addSubview(textField)            
            return cellView
            
        default:
            return nil
        }
        
    }
    
    func buildMenu() {
        let mainMenu = NSMenu()
        NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
        // **** App menu **** //
        let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
        let appMenu = NSMenu()
        appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
        appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q")
    }
    
    func buildWnd() {
        
        let _wndW : CGFloat = 400
        let _wndH : CGFloat = 300
        
        window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
        window.center()
        window.title = "Swift TableView Demo"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
        // **** TableView **** //
        let scrlView = NSScrollView(frame:NSMakeRect(10,10,380,240))
        let tableView = NSTableView(frame:NSMakeRect(0,0,364,240))
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        let nameColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("NameColumn"))
        nameColumn.title = "Name"
        nameColumn.width = 100
        tableView.addTableColumn(nameColumn)
        let hotkeyColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("HotkeyColumn"))
        hotkeyColumn.title = "Hotkey"
        hotkeyColumn.width = 200
        tableView.addTableColumn(hotkeyColumn)
        scrlView.documentView = tableView
        window.contentView!.addSubview(scrlView)
        
        // **** Quit btn **** //
        let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, _wndH - 40, 40, 40 ))
        quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
        quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
        quitBtn.title = "Q"
        quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
        window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
    }
       
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        buildMenu()
        buildWnd()
    }
    
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let app = NSApplication.shared
app.delegate = appDelegate
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
app.run()
```